# Make asynchronous call synchronize

Tags: c#, asynchronous, synchronization, waithandle

I trying to synchronize a asynchronous call.

The regular (**async**) flow look like:

1. Asking the server for data using telnet: 'Session.sendToTarget(message)'
2. The app move on doing other things....
3. When the server answer ready, the server send the result.
4. The app get the result and raise event "OnDataReceived"

The data from the server is critical for the next step so I want to hold EVERYTHING until it's received.

The **sync** flow should look like:

1. Asking the server for data: Session.sendToTarget(message)
2. Wait until the data received from the server

Using c#, I tried to sync the operation with 'WaitHandle.WaitOne(TimeToWaitForCallback)' unsuccessfully, It's seems that WaitOne halt the application for receiving incoming messages (I tried as well wait in other thred). Afther TimeToWaitForCallback time pass I get the incoming message that were halt deu to WaitOne action.

my attempt for making the code sync:

```
public virtual TReturn Execute(string message)
            {
                WaitHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false);
                var action = new Action(() =>
                                                 {
                                                     BeginOpertaion(message);
                                                     WaitHandle.WaitOne(TimeToWaitForCallback);
                                                     if (!IsOpertaionDone)
                                                         OnOpertaionTimeout();
                                                 });
                action.DynamicInvoke(null);
                return ReturnValue;
            }
```

The incoming raise this code:

```
protecte protected void EndOperation(TReturn returnValue)
        {
            ReturnValue = returnValue;
            IsOpertaionDone = true;
            WaitHandle.Set();
        }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Of course `WaitHandler.WaitOne` blocks the current thread and wait for the task until the handler is signaled. Isn't it what you want? You say you want "Wait until the data received from the server".

Comment: Yes, I want to wait, but the blocking prevent from my app to get the server incoming messages, so the handler is never signaled, it's stop wait on timeout.

Answer (score 2):

```
    AutoResetEvent mutex = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(delegate 
        { 
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.WriteLine("sleep over");
            mutex.Set(); 
        }));
    mutex.WaitOne();
    Console.WriteLine("done");
    Console.ReadKey();
```

place mutex.Set() to your eventhandler when the async opperation completes...

ps: I like thread over action notation :P

Comment: The async operation completes when the server send back (in new a session) the result, and not when the first operation completes.

Comment: you get an event, right? So WaitOne() on the caller and .Set within the eventhandler. Assuming that the "new session" is also a new thread. Otherwise you have to encapsulate the whole thing in a worker thread and wait for the completion (e.g. Thread.Join)

Answer (score 0):

ManualResetEvent can really help you in this case.

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0420__Thread/Useamanualeventobject.htm

Answer (score 0):

Below lines

> The regular (async) flow look like:

```
   Asking the server for data using telnet: 'Session.sendToTarget(message)' 
   The app move on doing other things.... 
   When the server answer ready, the server send the result. 
   The app get the result and raise event "OnDataReceived"
```

and making it to the following

```
Asking the server for data: Session.sendToTarget(message) 
Wait until the data received from the server
```

it is as good as blocking request so just call the Session.sendToTarget(message) synchronously. No point of making it asynchronous

Comment: I can't call it synchronously. I have no control on the session and how it's menage its' calls to the server.